Fetching Data from a .sql file in a Django Project
I have a django project. I have a dump of the data from a Mysql database in a .sql file and want to query some data from this file into my django project and display it.
I am fairly new to django. Need some help
My settings.py looks like this :
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


A .sql file is just a text file with sql statements in it. You need to import it back to mysql to be able run sql queries against it.
